# Actual meaning of windows services

Tags: windows-services

I just want the explanation to the question 'what does windows services basically means?' I want some real time example that i can relate 'windows services' with?

Comment: Well, there's a bunch of them shipped with Windows.  The Windows Update service, for example, and the Task Scheduler service.  Windows services are what you write when you want your code to run without a user having to log in and launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows services are background running processes. they dont have UI. Windows services are installed in windows based machines to do some particular tasks on the background like a job. Windows Services has .exe extension but cannot run like a application.

click 'start' in your windows machine, type 'services.msc' and press Enter. This will open windows services installed in your current machine with their active status. If you stop some service, Some relevant application may misbehave. i.e, If any windows application that uses this service for some background job the application would crash.

Antivirus scan, Task scheduler which does some task at specified time are examples of windows services.

In development perspective windows services has

1. OnStart event (Fires when services start)
2. OnStop event (Fires when services stop)
3. timerElapsed event (if you set the interval as 15 seconds, this event fires every 15 seconds)

These services can be created using windows services template in visual studio and installed, uninstalled using 'installutil'

```
installutil -i servicepath\service.exe  (installs service)
installutil -u servicepath\service.exe  (uninstalls service)
```

Windows services can also host wcf services with mex binding. if you have any particular question do let me know. accept if it is useful